# php session keeps redirecting to one page

Tags: php

The code keeps opening login.php with both wrong and correct login details. I intent to start a session every time someone tries to log in but only allows a authenticated attempt

```
<?php    
function login() {
     global $con;
     if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
       // $member_id = $_POST['member_id'];
       // $memberpass = $_POST['memberpass'];



    if( isset($_POST['member_id']) && isset($_POST['memberpass'])){

        $sql= "SELECT * from login ";
        $query=query($sql);


    if(isset($_SESSION["user"]))
        {
            if ($_SESSION['member_id'] = $_POST['member_id'] && $_SESSION['memberpass'] = $_POST['memberpass']);
            session_start();


            header('Location: index1.php');
        }
        else {
            header('Location: login.php');
        }
?>
```

Comment: You should start the session before anything, it shouldn't be conditional like this. Then are you sure you want to assign in the `if ($_SESSION['member_id'] = $_POST['member_id'] &&...` condition? `=` assigns, `==` compares. And you don't really check anything from the query (unless you have some sort of check there, but then your logic/structure seems very hard to work with)

Comment: It also seems highly inefficient to query all the data if you're just looking for one row. Then there's a question of hashing the password, which seems to be either in plaintext or using old, insecure methods, such as `sha1()` or `md5()`

Comment: I started a session at the beginning but it redirected too many times. This is where the session was started<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

session_regenerate_id();
//if(isset($_SESSION['member_id']))      // if there is no valid session
//{
    //header("Location: index.php");
    include'db_conn.php';
//}

Comment: The session needs to be set before you can check anything, so if you don't start the session at the very beginning of the script, you're checking against values that doesn't exist. You should enable error-reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`, it'll likely throw you some notices. But seems like you're walking into a lot of fall-pits when it comes to creating a secure login - you might want to look into using a framework that handles authentication for you.

Comment: `=` is assignment; `==` is comparison

Comment: Just a general point, try and avoid using `global`, if you need a connection in your function, pass it in as a parameter.  It makes testing your code much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### FIX PHP SESSION PROBLEM

```
<?php    
session_start();

//For debuging purpose
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', true);

print_r( $_SESSION );

function login() {
     global $con;
     if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
       // $member_id = $_POST['member_id'];
       // $memberpass = $_POST['memberpass'];



    if( isset($_POST['member_id']) && isset($_POST['memberpass'])){

        $sql= "SELECT * from login ";
        $query=query($sql);


    if(isset($_SESSION["user"]))
        {
            // remove semi colon at the end ;if ($_SESSION['member_id'] = $_POST['member_id'] && $_SESSION['memberpass'] = $_POST['memberpass']);
            if ($_SESSION['member_id'] == $_POST['member_id'] && $_SESSION['memberpass'] == $_POST['memberpass'])
            {
                header('Location: index1.php');
            }
            else {
               echo "Invalid User";
               //header('Location: login.php');
            }
        }
        else {
            header('Location: login.php');
        }
?>
```

- Line 24 corrected by removing semi colon at the end and added curly braces for logic
- added error_reporting to let your see any error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Than mate, lemme try this out

Comment: @BrandonOluoch if this answer helped you, don't forget to mark it as accepted to help others as well.

Comment: it returns no error but keeps opening login.php no matter the inputs

Comment: What error, share it so that we can all help out. Thanks

Comment: what i mean is...There is no error, but when I try loging it, i am redirected to login.php with both wrong and right login credentials

Comment: @BrandonOluoch OK.  I fixed the code now. copy if and use it. it should work.  you were using `=` instead of `==`  use a compare operator not assign operator